# Given a list of X number of floats, return a tuple of the average of the middle 3 floats and the lowest float of that list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mean, min

Example:

Input:

```
[6.4, 11.4, 7.6, 10.5, 8.1]
```

Expected output:

```
(9.83, 6.4)
```

9.83 (rounded off to nearest two decimal places) is the average of 11.4, 7.6 and 10.5 and 6.4 is the lowest float of the list.

Comment: Did you give it a try? Please share with us where you failed, so we can help you out

Comment: The first element in the output should be the avg of all the list members?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Use `statistics.mean` to get mean of the middle 3 elements and round them two places using `round`, to get minimum use `min`.

```
from statistics import mean
a=[6.4, 11.4, 7.6, 10.5, 8.1]
mid=len(a)//2 - 1 #for extracting n/2th-1 position
out=(round(mean(a[mid:mid+3]),2),min(a))
# (9.83, 6.4)
```

Note: This would raise error if `a` is empty.

[*Demo*](https://repl.it/repls/BountifulEachDemand) with some examples.